# how to Convert string into Json using Newton Json library

Tags: json, asp.net-ajax

sorry for the silly question, but i am stuck converting for example the following result from a method into Json

```
public string Test(string input) {
 return "Name:" + input;
}
```

to look like this 
{"Name":"Mike"}

Update:
Darin fixed first problem now i am using this way but it is not working

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

using(JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw)) {
 jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
 jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Name");
 jsonWriter.WriteValue("Mike");
}
```

I get

```
'{"Name":{"m_MaxCapacity":2147483647,"Capacity":16,"m_StringValue":"\\"Name\\": \\"Mike\\"","m_currentThread":0}}';
```

Comment: You can't change "from a method into Json"; you need a c# object, with properties, that will be represented in Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class:

```
public string Test(string input)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(new { Name = input });
}
```

Example usage:

```
string json = Test("Mike"); // json = {"Name":"Mike"}
```

---

UPDATE:

Didn't notice you wanted a solution using the [Json.NET library](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). Here's one:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Name = input });
```

Comment: man you just made my day, how stupid i was, thanks alot really